# How to install Beanstalkd in Red Hat Openshift?

Tags: queue, openshift, yum, beanstalkd, laravel-4.2

First I logged in to my application using ssh, in ubuntu terminal.

Then tried to install it using sudo `apt-get install beanstalkd`

But the result is:

```
test.rhcloud.com 123]\> sudo apt-get install beanstalkd
bash: /usr/bin/sudo: Permission denied
```

Then I found that I should use yum command to install packages, 
So tried the following method, and got the result as follows:

```
test.rhcloud.com 123]\> su -c 'yum install beanstalkd'
bash: /bin/su: Permission denied
```

Also tried this:

```
test.rhcloud.com 123]\> yum install beanstalkd
error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
CRITICAL:yum.main:

Error: rpmdb open failed
```

Any command with **yum** is resulting to the same error

```
error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
CRITICAL:yum.main:

Error: rpmdb open failed
```

I am using the Beanstalkd Queue in my Laravel 4.2 Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't install packages into a openshift gear, your best chances are:

- you can develop a cartridge and this will provide **beanstalkd**
- you run the **beanstalkd** binary from the userdata directory

Moreover beanstalkd is a work queue that must be installed on the host, this is really unfortunate because you can't run it on another gear on the openshift platform.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there any existing cartridge for beanstalkd available? So that I can add it to my application?

Comment: I don't know if  it exist, your best shot is to search for a company that provides beanstalkd as a service and link it to your app

Comment: Ok I will try that. Thank you